# How to resolve source member for multi-property mapping in AutoMapper?

Tags: c#, automapper, .net-core-2.1

I have DO and DTO classes:

```
public class DO
{
   public int Property1 { get; set; }
   public int Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class DTO
{
   public int MappedProperty1 { get; set; }
   public int MappedProperty2 { get; set; }
}
```

The mapping registration for the above classes are like below.

```
// From DO to DTO:
configuration.CreateMap<DO, DTO>()
   .ForMember(d => d.MappedProperty1, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Property1))
   .ForMember(d => d.MappedProperty2, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.Property1 + s.Property2));

// From DTO to DO:
configuration.CreateMap<DTO, DO>()
   .ForMember(d => d.Property1, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.MappedProperty1))
   .ForMember(d => d.Property2, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.MappedProperty1 - s.MappedProperty2));
```

Elsewhere in the code I need to get the destination property names in the mapping. I'm currently doing this by:

```
var map= mapper.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor<DTO, DO>();
var property = map.GetPropertyMaps().First(f => f.SourceMember == typeof(DTO).GetProperty("MappedProperty1"));
var name = property.DestinationProperty.Name;
```

This works fine with `MappedProperty1`. However, it does not work with `MappedProperty2` as there are two properties participating in the mapping. Instead, I get the error message:

"Sequence contains no matching element".

I also tried with the following instead of `First` filter and in debug I can see that the count in the list is zero.

```
var map= mapper.ConfigurationProvider.FindTypeMapFor<DTO, DO>();
var property = map.GetPropertyMaps().Where(w => w.SourceMember == typeof(DTO).GetProperty("MappedProperty2")).ToList();
```

How can I achieve this source name resolution for multi-property mapping?

Comment: Why do you need that?

Comment: I need to know which field on the dto maps/corresponds to do field at runtime because the request only contains information on some dto fields. It's to parse some strings that contain information about the dto as do.

Comment: I'm asking because that's an implementation detail, so you use at your own risk. Now, in those other cases, what you have is an expression, PropertyMap.CustomExpression I think. And you need a visitor to extract the source member names See [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/search?p=1&q=visitor&unscoped_q=visitor). But maybe you should take another approach, because it's getting messy :)

Comment: Thanks for the resource. I will see if it's feasible. I understand. Actually, any implementation of this requirement is likely to get messy. So far, for simpler 1-1 mappings, this approach gives me very clean code. So, I will try pursue it a bit more. Thanks for the advice!